# socat: EXEC does not relay correctly

Tags: c, socat

I have a small program that first outputs a string to the user and then takes an input. I instead want the program to work by sending and receiving from a port. To try to realize this I ran the command `socat TCP4-LISTEN:1337,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:./program`. From this command, I wanted to be able to run `nc 127.0.0.1 1337` and expected the program to:

1. Recieve the message from the program
2. Be able to provide input
3. Lost connetion

However, when running the program using `socat` it goes like this

1. Give input
2. Message received from the program
3. Give another input
4. Lost connection

I don't understand why this happens. Is there any fault on my part using the `socat` command? And if it is, please tell me what is missing/wrong.

Here is the program.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void vuln(void) {
    printf("Input\n");
    char buffer[256];
    gets(buffer); // potential buffer overflow
}

int main(void) {
    vuln();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`pty`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/549505/108618)?

Comment: That does seem to help. I now get the output first, but after that, I need to give an input twice.  I would want it to only ask for one input. By the way, what is pty?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21147/what-are-pseudo-terminals-pty-tty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426280/what-do-pty-and-tty-mean https://linux.die.net/man/7/pty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, `printf` is part of the buffered I/O library – data written to the stream is "buffered" in memory (i.e., not written directly the the kernel).

By default, `stdout` (the stream to which `printf` writes data) is a *line-buffered* stream, which means that bytes are stored in the in-memory buffer until a newline is written to the stream (or some other even that triggers flushing happens).

If standard output isn't associated with a terminal, then `stdout` is a *block-buffered* stream, which means that bytes are stored in the in-memory buffer until the buffer gets full.

When you run your program at the terminal, the `'\n'` in your call to `printf` triggers the flush (since it's line-buffered):

```
$ ./a.out
Input
whatever-you-type
$
```

If you redirect output to a file, you'll see a different behavior:

```
Terminal 1               Terminal 2
--------------------     --------------------
$ ./a.out > /tmp/out
                         $ cat /tmp/out
                         $
type-input
$
                         $ cat /tmp/out
                         Input
                         $
```

When you run `socat` without `pts`, the output stream is in block-buffered mode; when you run it with `pts` the output stream is in line-buffered mode.

If you want to override that behavior, you have a couple of options.  You can call a function to explicitly cause any buffered data to be flushed:

```c
printf("Input\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly set the buffering mode of the output stream before calling `printf`:

```c
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); // _IONBF = Unbuffered
printf("Input\n");
```

See Chapter 3 of Robert Love's book *Linux System Programming* for a more detailed explanation.